# Sql server 2016 split url backup into multiple files

Tags: sql-server, backup, azure-blob-storage

I have a database backing up into an Azure page blob via URL backups set up from SSMS. I am trying to find out how to split the backup into smaller chunks.  I have a 2 TB database that is now backing up in to one large file, I want to separate it into 4 smaller files. Any hints would be helpful.

Environment Summary: Azure VM with SQL 2016 Enterprise
Backup Method: URL Backup to Azure Page Blob
Security Involved: Key Vault and Credentials
Current Status: Backups working
Desired Status: Large Backups split into multiple files

I am ok with a powershell example.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should split it into multiple url in this way:

```
BACKUP DATABASE mydb
TO URL = 'https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/mydbBackupSetNumber2_0.bak',
URL = 'https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/mydbBackupSetNumber2_1.bak',
URL = 'https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/mydbBackupSetNumber2_2.bak'
WITH COMPRESSION, MAXTRANSFERSIZE = 4194304, BLOCKSIZE = 65536;
```

ref:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlcat/backing-up-a-vldb-to-azure-blob-storage